# jQuery validate giving error (.validate is not a function)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

Hy all I am using jQuery validate plugin it was working fine suddenly it stopped working when I checked the console for any errors it was giving me this error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

I have read many forums but all the solutions are not working for me please someone help me out here is my code.

This is the head portion

```
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/css/style.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>



    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

For the main body portion

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#addpro').validate();

        var form = $("#addpro");
        var itemm = $("#id_itemchoice").val();
        var itemmsize = $("#id_size").val();
        var itemmprice = $("#id_price").val();
        var wholesaleprice = $("#id_wholesale_price").val();
        var itemmdes = $("#id_description").val();
        var quantity = $("#id_quantity_received").val();

        if (itemm === "" || itemmsize === "" || itemmprice === "" || wholesaleprice === "") {
            $(".val-error, .error-message").show();
        } else {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {action: 'insert_consultant_post', itemchoice: itemm, size: itemmsize, price: itemmprice, description: itemmdes, quantity: quantity},
                url: "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Please have a look at it and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Ensure jquery and jquery-validate libraries are loaded successfully.

Comment: They are loaded I have ensured it 2 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you are using wp_enqueue_script() from WordPress?
Check the docs - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

```
wp_enqueue_script()
```

I think you can simplify your ajax post way more.
Check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ftr08w9L/

```
$.post()
```

Ofcourse you would want to adjust the fiddle for your code. I've also added some comments to help you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot with your solution the issue is resolved